# SSL Client Authentication on BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, ssl

Is there any way to perform SSL Client(Mutual) Authentication on a BlackBerry phone? the closest thing I have found is the TLS10Connection/SSL30Connection, but I havent found any way to set any options to do anything, let alone pass it a certificate and use client authentication.

Since BlackBerry (as far as I know) does not have JNI I cant compile openssl and use it...maybe there is a Java ssl library I could include in my BlackBerry project but I dont know of one.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I still dont know whether or not it is possible using the BlackBerry API and am still interested to know if it is, but I found out that BouncyCastle has a J2ME library for which seems to be compatible with BlackBerry.  Luckily, the most recent version (1.46) has added "support for client side SSL to the TLS API".  So while I still dont know how to do it yet it at least seems like it will be possible.